# Designing a SaaS on a single database, multi-tenant (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, roles, saas

I'm working on a *SaaS* product and trying to figure out the best way to design the database for my scenario, which I think is pretty standard.

I should not that I don't have an experience designing such a database.

I tired researched online, but there isn't really any info I could find about implementation. There are quite a few comparing the different multi-tenant architectures.

For the multi-tenant approach, I decided go with a *single database* - seemed to be the most fitting.

Here's the basic list of what should be supported:

- Multiple clients, all separated, no sharing of data between them.
- Each client has it's own user base (staff/employees).
- The client's staff members have different access levels to the system (exposure to different areas, ability to perform certain actions)
- Each client have it's own customers.

I can wrap my head around the basic concept of having the `tenant_id` on any table belongs to that *tenant*. I guess my issue is more with how to combine it with different access levels per client's staff member.

How would you go about it? 
Any reference some implementation of such a DB?

Thanks

---

**Update**

After @dmfy answer, I gave it some thought and came up with this solution:

```
account
 -id
 -name

user
 -id
 -account_id
 -username
 -password

role
 -id
 -account_id
 -name

user_role
 -user_id
 -role_id

access
 -id
 -role_id
 -name

role_access
 -role_id
 -access_id

session
 -account_id
 -user_id
 -token
```

I'll explain-

The `role` table is essentially a "group" of users associated with a list of permissions/access levels.

The `access` table represents a single permission. An area of the platform, an action that can (or cannot) be performed.

A row in  the `session` table is created after a successful login. Each time there's a call to the server, if the user has been verified against the token, I will lookup the roles for that user (using the `session.user_id` on the `user_roles` and collect it's `access` list using `role.id` on `role_access.role_id`).

Once I have the access list I can check against the request and see if the user is permitted to perform the action.

- Notes

  - `role` can be customized for each tenant/account (e.g one can have "Management" and "Employees" and another can have "Management", "Support", and "Sales" ), hence the association with `account`.
  - `access` on the other hand, is platform-wide. The platform have the same set of areas and actions across all tenants. So there is not need to associate it with a specific account.
  - An improvement to the `access` lookup could be to store the access list on the session on login, to eliminate the double join (get all the user's roles, get all the roles' access lists).

Questions

- Firstly, what is your overall opinion on the design. Do you see any flaws?
- Is saving the `account_id` on the `session` really needed/a good idea?
- Is having the *server* check whether the user has access to a certain resource is the standard way of doing this? Is there a way to do this as part of the itself query (e.g get an error from the DB itself)?

Comment: multiple tenants in the same table is the worst choice. Why did you default to it?

Comment: Easier to maintain single DB, scales better, more cost effective... What are your votes against it?

Comment: There are reasons not to do it: some industry regulations can require stricter data segregation, upgrades/migrations affect all tenants no matter what, and it's difficult to work with individual tenant data sets. I gave a [talk](https://vimeo.com/223984368) about a technique for managing that last in 2017.

Comment: I see. This is why I don't consider the different approaches as better or worse. More as more fitting to what you're trying to achieve. In my case I don't any of those regulations or needs so the single DB looks the most fitting.

Comment: @yohairosen After almost 2 years, are you happy with the database structure? Do you still use it? Would you change anything looking back?

Answer (score 3):

You might get a better answer by describing the requirements before you outline the solution.

Your design seems to describe an authorisation scheme. It looks fairly credible - I'd summarize it in natural language as:

- A tenant is an account.
- An account has many users.
- A user can have
  many roles.
- Roles grant access to many permissions.
- The system
  maintains a list of sessions, mapping requests to users; this in turn
  allows the system to check whether the user has permissions for a
  given action.

Without knowing your requirements, that seems fairly reasonable. You may want to include a link from "account" to something your application recognizes as "tenant".

The big question is how you will use this data in your application. Checking permissions - especially fine-grained permissions - for each request could be expensive.

The specific solution here depends heavily on your application framework - many have built-in authentication/authorization models, and it's usually a good idea to use those built-in features.

For ideas on how to implement this, you could look at [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan), an authorization framework for Ruby on Rails, or [Authority](https://github.com/efficiently/authority-controller) for Laravel.

It's also not clear how the actual data in your system will be linked to an account - if your system tracks widgets, does the "widgets" table have an "account_id" column? If so, how does your application track who is and is not allowed to access that row?

Comment: I agree and your list summarizes it well. What would be the benefits of having both tenant and account? The (big) question you asked is exactly what I wanted to get some opinions about- I was thinking it might be expensive as well- is there another way of doing it? what about the "improvement" i suggested in my question? cacheing the list of permissions in the session? ... And yes, all relevant "objects"/"rows" will have an account_id- Taking your example, I will check if the user's role has a "access" of "widget" associated with it. Thoughts?

Comment: I've updated the answer - it is really a question for the application framework you're using, rather than the database design. In general, though, I think super granular permissions are probably overkill - you might get a cleaner design by modelling the roles your application needs to support.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're conflating *database* users with *application* users. In a SaaS product with a shared-schema model, individual users won't have direct acess to the database; instead, your application connects as a single user with appropriate rights on all objects it needs. What you're worried about is what areas of the application users can access and what actions they can take. This means you need to build your authorization model into your schema.

The simplest possible model has two levels of access: regular users and administrators. This can be represented with a `users` table having a `tenant_id` to associate individual logins with the correct client, and an `is_admin` flag. Your application then ensures that only users with the flag set can access administrative functionality. If your authorization model is more complex, design your schema appropriately (`users` may have a many:many relationship with `roles`, for example).

Note also that a `tenant_id` column is only strictly required for tables directly related to `tenants`; if you have a `profiles` table with a `user_id`, you can trace the relationship back to the tenant through `users`. In some cases it may make sense to add the `tenant_id` to avoid long join chains.

Comment: Thanks for sending my in the right direction. Updated my question.